# check if no line contains string in given field

Tags: text-processing, awk, gawk

I need to search for thousands of strings one by one if they exists on a second column and if not do action against each such string which was not found in second column of any line

file:

```
line a
line b
line c
line z
line d
line e
line z
line z
```

file2:

```
line a
line b
line c
line d
line e
```

What I tried:

```
$ awk '{if($2=="z") {c++} } END { if(c==0) {print "no \"z\""} else { print c" \"z\"" }}' file
3 "z"
$ awk '{if($2=="z") {c++} } END { if(c==0) {print "no \"z\""} else { print c" \"z\"" }}' file2
no "z"
$ awk '{if($2=="z") {c++} } END { if(c!=0) {print "no \"z, action will be done\""} }' file
no "z, action will be done"
```

Is my code ok, or could be simplified/optimized yet?

Update:
@RomanPerekhrest
referring to your code, how to process only "else" or add negation to "c?" and then ignore else?

I was trying with:
(c? : "no"),

but it does not work.

@αғsнιη, thank you, finally I have working script

```
$ awk -v s="z" '$2==s{ c++ }END{ printf (!c ? NOP : "prepare command1\nprepare command2\nprepare command3\n") }' file
prepare command1
prepare command2
prepare command3
$ awk -v s="z" '$2==s{ c++ }END{ printf (!c ? NOP : "prepare command1\nprepare command2\nprepare command3\n") }' file2
$
```

or

```
$ awk -v s="z" '$2==s{ c++ }END{if(c==0) printf "prepare command1\nprepare command2\nprepare command3\n" }' file2
prepare command1
prepare command2
prepare command3
$ awk -v s="z" '$2==s{ c++ }END{if(c==0) printf "prepare command1\nprepare command2\nprepare command3\n" }' file
$
```

Comment: Use `!c?` or change to `c?"no":c` or `!c?NOP:"no"`

Answer (score 1):

Via **`awk`** dynamic variable/argument `-v <var>=<value>`:

Test case for string `z`:

```
awk -v s="z" '$2==s{ c++ }END{ printf "%s \042%s\042\n", (c? c : "no"), s }' file
```

The output:

```
3 "z"
```

---

Test case for string `w`:

```
awk -v s="w" '$2==s{ c++ }END{ printf "%s \042%s\042\n", (c? c : "no"), s }' file
```

The output:

```
no "w"
```

Comment: Why not exit immediately after the the first time incrementing `c`? The OP says he has thousands of strings `s` to be checked so depending upon each file's size, significant savings could be had by replacing `{c++}` with `{c=1; exit}`, no?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood this correctly you want to check if second column has specific alphabet, if yes, so please try below `awk` script which will report which one is exist with corresponding count and which one doesn't with `"NOT FOUND!"` remark.

```
awk -v alphabet="$(printf "%s" {a..z})" 'BEGIN{ split(alphabet, arr, "") }
    { chrs[$2]++ } END{ for(y in chrs) for(x in arr)
        { if(arr[x] in chrs) {print y, chrs[y]; delete arr[x]; break }
            else{ print arr[x]" NOT FOUND!"; delete arr[x] }
        }
}' infile
```

Output:

```
w 1
z 3
a 1
b 1
c 1
f NOT FOUND!
g NOT FOUND!
h NOT FOUND!
i NOT FOUND!
j NOT FOUND!
k NOT FOUND!
l NOT FOUND!
m NOT FOUND!
n NOT FOUND!
o NOT FOUND!
p NOT FOUND!
q NOT FOUND!
r NOT FOUND!
s NOT FOUND!
t NOT FOUND!
u NOT FOUND!
v NOT FOUND!
d 1
x NOT FOUND!
y NOT FOUND!
e 1
```